# How to passing data to modal Materializecss

Tags: javascript, php, materialize

My website uses the Materialize CSS for CSS framework and PHP for the back-end language. But, I have some problem. I want to make edit data features on modal, but I don't know how to passing data to the modal. What should I do?

**This is my modal content code:**

```
<!-- Modal Start (Edit Kamar) -->
<div id="edit-kamar" class="modal z-depth-0">
   <div class="modal-content white">
      <h5 class="grey-text text-darken-2"><b>Perbarui Data</b></h5>
      <form class="row">
         <div class="col s12">
            <div class="row">
               <div class="input-field col s12">
                  <input id="nomor" type="text" name="no_kamar" class="validate">
                  <label for="nomor">Nomor Kamar</label>
               </div>
            </div>
            <!--  -->
            <div class="row">
               <div class="input-field col s12">
                  <input id="deskripsi" type="text" name="fasilitas" class="validate">
                  <label for="deskripsi">Fasilitas</label>
               </div>
            </div>
            <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light blue" type="submit" name="edit_kamar">edit
               <i class="material-icons right">add</i>
            </button>
         </div>
      </form>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
      <a class="modal-close waves-effect waves-light btn-small grey">batal</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you have to fetch data from server by ajax when ( click to open the model ) and show the data to model by javascript or jquery

Comment: Sorry,you have the example? Because I just have a little bit experience in javascript...

Comment: do you know ajax ? https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_ajax.asp